# couldn't download using wget or curl with authentication

Tags: curl, wget, nvidia, tensorrt

Trying to download the library from NVIDIA that require authentication.
I could download from the browser as normal. But I need to download it in the server (no browser) terminal.

I tried with several options, doesn't work.

```
curl -u myuseremail:mypassword https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/tensorrt/5.1/ga/local_repos/nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1804-cuda10.1-trt5.1.5.0-ga-20190427_1-1_amd64.deb
```

and

```
wget --http-user=myemailaddress --http-password=mypassword https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/tensorrt/5.1/ga/local_repos/nv-tensorrt-repo-ubuntu1804-cuda10.1-trt5.1.5.0-ga-20190427_1-1_amd64.deb
```

It works for other downloads, except for this NVIDIA login authentication downloads. Pretty weird.

Note* However, I download locally and `SCP` to my server, but that's not what I am looking for, what if the file size is massive and what internet speed is too slow or bandwidth restriction.

Answer (score 3):

After checking through the various source, found the working answer.
I had to download a chrome extension first -> `LinkRedirect Trace`

once I have that, I first tried to download the package but paused (too huge size), then through the extension, I copy the values in of location as shown in the figure below. Then `wget` to the server terminal. download filename is a bit weird but works well. The value of `location` contains your login tokens.

> Note* The image is trimmed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the link to download the file and checkout the header for that request by `right click + inspect elements ==> network tab`

It will have the authentication token with the download link. Then ==>

`wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/tensorrt/secure/7.1/..........`

and it should start downloading.

[image: The get url to download with wget]